# Google Cloud vision couldn't detect one character

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I have used Google Cloud Vision API for my small project to detect text from an image. The API works very well almost text in the image be detected by the API but I found when the image has only one character in a line, the API will skip it.

Do you have any solution for this problem? I try to change color and resize the image but it still not work.

for example please look : [The API can detect only 'AMATA' but not 'S']

[image]

Comment: I dare say it's probably done on purpose for accuracy purposes and to prevent lots of single characters from being picked up by the detector

Comment: This issue may be related with block detection for a single character. Here is a [related FR](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111135589) about this issue. You can star the issue to get notification about its updates.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something related to Vision API model. There is a [related FR](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111135589) about this issue and you can star the issue to get notification about its updates